# Generate multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, random-generation, autoregressive

Suppose that I want to generate tri-variate Gaussian time series $\{(X_{1i}, X_{2i}, X_{3i}), i=1,2,...,n\}$ with a correlation structure across the three time series; that is, $(X_{1i}, X_{2i}, X_{3i}) \sim N((0,0,0), \Sigma)$, where $\Sigma=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \ r \ r \\ r \ 1 \ r \\ r \ r \ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Function mvrnorm() in R can be used to achieve the goal like the following:

```
r <- 0.3
Sigma <- matrix(c(1,r, r, r, 1, r, r, r, 1), 3, 3)
library('MASS')
mydata <- mvrnorm(n=100, rep(0, 3), Sigma)
```

However, if I would like to also specify a temporal structure in the time series like, for example,  autoregressive model AR(1), how can I do that?

Comment: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tsDyn/docs/VAR.sim

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks a lot for the pointer! It does look like what I'm looking for.